# Python Insert into json

Tags: python, json

so I need to make a little json database with Python and JSON and insert new data into it.

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
{
    "One": "catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567",
    "Two": ["catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567", "catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567"]
}
```

So I want to insert multiple instances of like this:

```
{
    "One": "catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567",
    "Two": ["catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567", "catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567"],
    "One": "John.Jones@outlook.com:1234567",
    "Two": ["John.Jones@outlook.com:1234567", "John.Jones@outlook.com:1234567"],
    "One": "Matt.Demon@outlook.com:1234567",
    "Two": ["Matt.Demon@outlook.com:1234567", "Matt.Demon@outlook.com1234567"],
    "One": "Adam.Baker@outlook.com:1234567",
    "Two": ["Matt.Demon@outlook.com:1234567", "Matt.Demon@outlook.com:1234567"],

}
```

(I know this is invalid json syntax, i'm not sure what the correct would be).

1. Let's say I want to insert "Daniel.Michaelson@outlook.com:1234567" into the json, so it would add

   "One": "Daniel.Michaelson@outlook.com:1234567",
   "Two": [""],

How would I do it?

2. Let's say I want to insert another row into Two, for Matt.Demon@outlook.com, how would I do this in Python?

Thank you!

Comment: You do not modify JSON.  You read the JSON into a Python structure using `json.loads`, then you modify the Python structure and write it back out.  And as you say, it's not valid to have multiple identical keys.  Perhaps you really want a list of small objects instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said this isn't a valid json so your question isn't very clear. Jsons are built from keys and values, however keys need to be injective. This means that every two keys should be different from each other.

Going back to your question. In python dictionary is used to store a json like data. So you actually need to store all your data in a dictionary and than convert it to json. for example:

```
import json

data = {"One": "catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567",
    "Two": ["catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567", "catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567"]
        }

json_s = json.dumps(data)
```

if you already have a json string and want to convert it to dictionary use loads:

```
data2 = json.loads(json_s)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the basic idea.  You might consider having an "import_data" function that reads from your file and returns the data structure, and an "export_data" function that writes it back out.

```
import json
jjj = """\
[
    {
        "One": "catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567",
        "Two": ["catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567", "catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567"]
    }
]"""

data = json.loads( jjj )

data.append({
    "One": "John.Jones@outlook.com:1234567",
    "Two": ["John.Jones@outlook.com:1234567", "John.Jones@outlook.com:1234567"]
})
data.append({
    "One": "Matt.Demon@outlook.com:1234567",
    "Two": ["Matt.Demon@outlook.com:1234567", "Matt.Demon@outlook.com1234567"]
})
data.append({
    "One": "Adam.Baker@outlook.com:1234567",
    "Two": ["Matt.Demon@outlook.com:1234567", "Matt.Demon@outlook.com:1234567"]
})

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "One": "catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567",
        "Two": [
            "catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567",
            "catherine.hamilton@outlook.com:1234567"
        ]
    },
    {
        "One": "John.Jones@outlook.com:1234567",
        "Two": [
            "John.Jones@outlook.com:1234567",
            "John.Jones@outlook.com:1234567"
        ]
    },
    {
        "One": "Matt.Demon@outlook.com:1234567",
        "Two": [
            "Matt.Demon@outlook.com:1234567",
            "Matt.Demon@outlook.com1234567"
        ]
    },
    {
        "One": "Adam.Baker@outlook.com:1234567",
        "Two": [
            "Matt.Demon@outlook.com:1234567",
            "Matt.Demon@outlook.com:1234567"
        ]
    }
]
```